# Should we have a kind of dictionary of tools?

Tags: discussion

I'm not a english native speaker and to be fully honest, I probably don't even know the name of the tools in my first language.

*Should we consider having a list of the (more or less) commonly used domestic tools with a picture of them?*

I made a sample answer in community wiki, feel free to edit/improve it.

We could also consider to somehow classify them.

I think that such a little dictionary might be very useful for people to ask, answer and understand posts.

Comment: This is WAY too broad. There are so many tool for so many things. If you are having issues you would be better to look them up individually. You also have to worry about regional terms and experience based identification where some tools have different names. If this stems from a specific question as for clarification from teh author and I am sure they will add more information or additional resources in their answers.

Comment: Just to clarify this would not be made better by narrowing to a particular craft. It would still be too broad at that point as well. I do appreciate the question though it is good to bring these topics up.

Comment: Indeed, after googling a bit further the different tools, this seems very broad :). @Matt I propose that you transform your comment into an answer so that I can accept it to show that: "ok this is a bad idea :)".

Comment: You're right I should have just answered.

Comment: If we were more specifically directed, this might work but with potentially hundreds of different crafts with thousands of different tools, there's really no way to maintain something like this.

Comment: I'm in agreement with everyone above, I just wanted to comment to say, if we were ever to do something like this we would need to break it up by craft and we would need everyone to realize that there's never going to be a way for us to be complete. Now in saying that I agree with Matt that we should let people ask questions about specifics and not try and create a dictionary.

Comment: There's nothing "too broad" about the **meta** question... please don't VTC it... That's silly. Questions like this are important in deciding our content. If you disagree with the proposal, [downvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47635/284336)... but there's no reason to close this question.

Comment: @Catija, Yes I've done IT, so I understand making dB entries into eternity.  But Yes it is possible to have a weaver's shuttle, have a different name, in the same language, regionally.  Shouldn't that be given as a sub-item.  We are here anyway to disseminate information, not constrict it.  But also, there are different types of shuttles, each having their own name also. Then we can get into the specific parts of different shuttles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## This would be WAY too broad.

There are so many tool for so many things. If you are having issues you would be better to look them up individually. You also have to worry about regional terms and experience based identification where some tools have different names. The Q&A format does not lend well to list and some of these crafts can have dozens of tools.

## What you can do instead

If this stems from a specific question ask for clarification from the author and I am sure they (or someone else that can via an edit) will add more information or additional resources in their answers.

Comment: Ok. You need to seriously chill. Meta is the place where we can ask literally anything, and anyone should be comfortable doing so.

Comment: @Zizouz212 What? I am not going overboard or anything. You make it seem like I am attacking the user? We can't have lists of tools for trades. The lists would be too large and this the Q&A method does not deal well with lists. .

Comment: Having header sized, all caps words as the first sentence of the post does certainly come across as strong and invasive, and it presents a slightly harsh tone. I don't disagree with the content of the post, but rather with it's delivery.

Comment: @Zizouz212 That would be a style choice for me that I use in _many_ of my posts. As always body language is hard to read in text. I am using those by there name: as headings. Also the only emphasis was on the word Way

Comment: @Zizouz212 On the head, we are here to cooperatively collaborate.  Sit down and get along!

Comment: @Matt, once again a restriction of the software we are using, not on the amount of correct information available. It is out there, don't you want to have it ?

Answer (score 2):

I have to disagree **strongly** with Matt here. There is a very reasonable question in the making here.

Like all fields, there are specialized and highly specific terms. Programmers, I would expect you to define me what a "string" or a "bit shift" is. Doctors, I would expect you to tell me what an "ultrasound" or an "echocardiogram" is.

Arts and crafts is no doubt, going to be somewhat similar. I've already seen terms that I've never heard before in my life - and that's coming from a teacher. [lapidary](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lapidary) and [lathe](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lathe) are already examples of tags that I've never seen to this day.

The discussion has merit: here's my view on this.

If there is a term/tool/object/concept that you have never heard before, I see a couple options. For the sake of providing an example, let's just say we are trying to figure out what the word "crocheting" means.

1. Ask a question

   Ask a specific question, and you can expect a reasonably informed answer. It will likely also be a formal answer, giving you plenty of information you need. But this may take time, and for specialized tools, it may take a while.

   Make sure though, that you don't ask for a *list*. That will be broad, and won't be received well. The answers are endless, and it would also be incredibly difficult to maintain. Ask about a single tool, not a list of them.
2. Ask in chat

   There's already a friendly community hanging out in the site's chatrooms, [and I highly encourage you to meet them!](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38932/imagination-fabrication-station) They'll be able to provide a quick answer to your questions, and they'll be able to provide you answers for any questions you have on the spot.
3. Just for show? I don't have a third idea... Read the first two :)

Comment: _Make sure though, that you don't ask for a list_ That is specifically what the op is suggesting we do though.

Comment: List-based answers tend to not receive a lot of attention over time and become stale or lose value as a consequence. The sites I moderate very heavily discourage lists for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

**Consider using tags for this**, rather than a Q&A (whether on main site or meta).

In addition to helping categorize questions at a glance, tags have two wiki style definitions: the short snippet you see when hovering, and a longer description that can be much more detailed. A hypothetical tag `saw`, for example, could have a list of some of the more common types of craft saws.

This method also means anyone who doesn't know a term just needs to click on the tag, and they're taken directly to the resource that can teach them more of the basics -- rather than needing to search meta, ask in comments or chat, or go off-site.

There are a lot of very good reasons to have well organized tags, and a central glossary is one way to turn them into an asset!

Comment: The tag would probably be "saws" but, yes. We already have several tool-related tags. :)

Comment: @Catija Ha, yes, of course -- the plural issue XD

Comment: @Catija, we have copping saw, scroll saw, finish saw, framing saw, single buck saw, dual buck saw, ripping saw, crosscut saw.  I haven't even got to paragraph two of "Modern Industry" ... that's the part I memorized 35 years ago.... in college.

Answer (score 0):

**Different types of saw:**

- [Coping saw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coping_saw)

[image]

- [Jigsaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jigsaw_(power_tool))

[image]

- [Circular saw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_saw)

[image]

- [Bandsaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandsaw)

[image]

- [Hand saw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_saw)

[image]

Comment: For example you are missing dozens of saws.